# Ordering references with Mendeley

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I'm using TeXstudio to write a document. For the references I'm using Mendeley Desktop (for scientific articles/books), that automatically puts the references in latex.

I'm currently using this codes:

```
\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

The references work fine, but I want them to be in a order of appearance and apperantly the unsrt code is not working. I've tried unsrtnat also, but does not seem to work..

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)  illustrating your problem.

Comment: Which order of apearance are you referring to: The order in which ou cite them in your .tex file or the order in which they are listed in your .bib file. The `unsrt` citation style should give you the former.